# Introduction to lollipop error

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am creating my new android app on lollipop.

activity

> ```
>  import android.os.Bundle;
>  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
>  import android.view.Menu;
>  import android.view.MenuItem;
>   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
> ```

and styles.xml

> ```
> <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
>     <!-- Main theme colors -->
>     <!-- your app branding color for the app bar -->
>     <item name="android:colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
>     <!-- darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
>     <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
> </style>
> ```

ok when i do theme.appcompat.light the app runs, but the color primary is not taken.instead some light gray is shown.

And if i do like the tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/material/get-started.html

i am getting the following crash

11-18 19:34:23.657: E/AndroidRuntime(29410): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Answer (score 0):

When Extending the AppCompat Theme, there is no need to use 'android:' values Anymore.

Try this in your style:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_color1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_color2</item>
</style>
```

Also Make Sure your Application defined in the Manifest is using your Theme. Example Manifest Entry:

```
<application
    android:name=".ExampleApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
```